# Чтение из файла, запись в файл pascal

Tags: pascal

Приветствую программеры.

Каким способом, лучше всего реализовать чтение из одного файла, и запись результа в другой?

задания примерно такого типа, поэтому можно показать и на этом примере

```
const m = 10;
var
x,z : array [1..m] of real;
i,j : integer;

begin
j := 0;
for i := 1 to m do
begin
     write('Z[',i,']=>');
     readln(z[i]);
     if z[i] <> 0 then
        begin
             j := j + 1;
             x[j] := z[i];
        end;
end;
for i := 1 to j do
writeln('X[',i,']=',x[i]);
readln;
end.
```

Зарание спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно записать/прочитать массив, то вот пример.

```
 Var
      FF: Text;
      Mas: Array[0..999] Of Integer;
      i, n: Word;

    begin

      Write('n = ');
      ReadLn(n);

      Randomize;

      Assign(FF, 'massiv.dat'); // связываю с файловой переменной
      Rewrite(FF); // открываю для записи
      For i:=0 To N-1 Do  // запись
        Begin
          Mas[i]:=Random(100)-Random(100);
          WriteLn(FF, Mas[i]); // записываю элемент
        End;
      Close(FF); // закрываю

      i:=0;
      Reset(FF); // открываю для чтения
      While Not(Eof(FF)) Do // чтение (пока не достигнут конец файла)
        Begin
          ReadLn(FF, Mas[i]); // читаю элемент
          WriteLn(Mas[i]);
          Inc(i);
        End;
      Close(FF); // закрываю

      ReadLn;
    end.
```

В данном примере я записываю массив в файл и из того же файла его читаю. Доработать несложно: завести ещё одну файловую переменную, связать её с другим файлом, открыть файл для записи и в цикле чтения из одного файла записывать в другой.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, помогло

Answer (score 0):

```
var
...
  f1, f2: File;
  x: Integer;
...
begin
...
  readln(f1, x);
...
  writeln(f2, x);
...
end.
```